# How to make a counter in pic16f877a

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

This is a program in pic16f877a that should count with auto increments and then reset at 0X0F. However, its not working(it does not count on proteus just displays zero). How do I get the counter to work?

```
#include    <16f877a.h>
#fuses      XT,NOWDT
#use        delay(clock=4000000)
int c;
int  portb;   
int trisb;
void main()
{
   int c=0;
   portb=0;
   trisb=0b00000000;
   while(1)
   {
      if(c<=16) {
      portb=c;
      c=c+1;
      delay_ms(100);
   }
   else if (c>=0x0F)
   { c=0x00;}
   }
}
```

Comment: You did not say **what**  is not working. Are you assuming this code will change bits on the peripheral port b?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly is intended to count, what is supposed to trigger a count, and what you think "auto increments" means.  *"Not working"* is meaningless without a spec of what "working" is.  We could probably figure this out, but with the sloppy writing and disrespect of the volunteers here (you couldn't even be bothered to capitalize the first letter of the question, nor the first letter of the title) it's easier just to close this and move on.

Answer (score 1):

"Not working" is not a useful description. Please state any errors or warnings from the compiler and describe exactly what the functional discrepancies may be. Nevertheless there are some obvious things wrong.

You are declaring int variables with similar names to the char PORTB and TRISB registers, which are defined in the .h file. Note that case is significant in C identifiers.

They will typically be defined something like this:

> extern volatile unsigned char           PORTA               @ 0x00C;

but look in the .h file..

There may be other things wrong- did you intend to write C+=1; ? And if so, why 
twice?

---

The Microchip IDEs have a decent simulation capability which you can use to single step through the program from the C source. It's worth learning how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't incrementing your counter anywhere that I can tell.

```
while(1)
   {
      if(c<=16) {
      c=1;
      portb=c;
      c=1;
      delay_ms(100);
   }
   else if (c>=0x0F)
    { c=0x00;}
```

}

There's nowhere in this block where the c var will come off of 1.  It's set to 1 if less than 16, and that's it. 
Likely you want to set one like `c++` to increment by one, and delete the second `c=1`.  Or maybe your `portb = c` is backwards, and neither `c=1` should be there.  I don't know.

Comment: yes i made that change but it still does not increment on proteus